# Is AES slower to encrypt than MD5?

Tags: encryption, hash, aes, md5

Is this the right interperation of this diagram:
http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html

- AES/CCM

  MiB/Second:61

  Cycles Per Byte:28.6
- MD5

  MiB/Second:255

  Cycles Per Byte:6.8

And does that also mean that MD5 is easier to crack when using the same password (so same key length and key strength).

Comment: AES and MD5 do not do the same thing. One is an [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) algorithm (technically, the core of an encryption algorithm), the other is a [digest algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_algorithm). [It makes no sense to compare them](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).

Comment: Well, you can brute force both of them to crack the original input. So assume you would have a AES key and you know 26/32 of the characters, Is it true that it will still be slower to crack the 6 characters you don't know, when using AES, because of the lower MiB/Second.

Comment: Edit your question then. Be sure to state your assumptions very precisely: as usual when it comes to security, a small detail can make a world of difference.

Answer (score 5):

MD5 is a hashing algo, a bit like a CRC checksum algo, the data is not encrypted, it is hased, and thus unrecoverable. It is in fact fast to compute.

Encryption algo, are a 2-way system, data can be encrypted and decrypted with a valid key. They usually involve more loops and shifting then checksum algos, thus slower.

Choosing between MD5 or AES will depends on your needs and requirements.
Bare in mind that MD5 is not secure anymore and should not be used. Prefer SHA-256 instead.

Edit: from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2),

> NIST's directive that U.S. government agencies **must stop uses of SHA-1
>   after 2010**. Currently, the best public attacks break 41 of the 64
>   rounds of SHA-256 or 46 of the 80 rounds of SHA-512

Comment: SHA-1 shouldn't be used either, for the same reason.

Comment: that's correct abt SHA-1, post edited, tx.

Comment: Should we just have a hashing is not encryption banner on this site?

Comment: Your wikipedia quote is very misleading.  SHA-1 should not be used as there's a theoretical collision attack.  Actual SHA-2 hashes (e.g., SHA-256/SHA-512) is probably fine to use; there's no publicly known attacks on it.  Weakness against a simplified version of them have been found (e.g., use 41 instead of 64 rounds construct a file/string that gives an identical hash with only 2^253.5 attempts as opposed to the 2^256 that yo expect (so your attack could be 6 times faster; but still isn't feasible to do in the lifetime of the universe with all of google's computational power)).

Comment: "_Bare in mind that MD5 is not secure anymore and should not be used._" for which purpose???

Comment: Any purpose, really. You should be phasing it out and replacing with stronger hashing algorithms add stated above.

Comment: @ktothez I think there should be a couple quick questions when signing up, one of them being whether MD5 is an encryption algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

MD5 is a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), not an encryption function. It yields a fixed-size output (128 bits) regardless of the input size. It is not meant to be reversible. Thus, it can not be compared with AES: what MD5 does, AES cannot do, and what AES does, MD5 cannot do.

One situation where you can meaningfully compare processing speeds of MD5 and AES is in protocols where the same data is both encrypted (e.g. with AES) *and* covered by a [Message Authentication Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) such as HMAC, which is based upon a hash function (possibly MD5). One such protocol is [SSL/TLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246). In that case, we can try to see which of the encryption and the MAC uses most of the CPU budget. Usually, encryption is more expensive than hashing, which the numbers you give show. Note, though, that MD5 is known to have a number of weaknesses. The standard hash function which is believed to be "as strong" as AES is SHA-256, and SHA-256 processing speed is not much better than that of AES, on commonly used CPU.

Another situation is a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). You can build a PRNG out of a block cipher (such as AES) by encrypting successive values of a counter (this is called CTR mode). You can also build a PRNG out of a hash function by HMAC-ing successive values of a counter. In that case, this works, for the hash function, on its *output* bandwidth, not its *input* bandwidth, and it requires hashing many very small messages instead of one big message. Usual hash functions, including MD5, turn out to be disappointingly slow when used that way.

This explains why we define block ciphers such as the AES, instead of using a one-size-fits-all hash function everywhere.